# Authenticate user in a url

Tags: authentication

There is a username/passowrd associated with a client to use our website url(https) and send data.It is not a web service and it is a web page(aspx) to recieve the data. What would be the best way to authenticate it? Should the user be created in the server machine and gets validated against it? or it is not a right thing to do and we should secure the url in a different way?

Thanks,

Valery

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if it's a secure page, you should be using HTTPS. This will alleviate all of your external security issues as far as securing the URL.

As far as passing the username/password within the URL, there is specific, defined protocol for that...

```
https://username:password@www.example.com
```

Comment: Thanks Koji for your reply. It is already HTTPS url, but user name and password are added as parameters to the url.Would that be secure enough to validate it against the server machine?